# How to interpret Zend Developer Tools Toolbar - Memory Usage

Tags: performance, memory, zend-framework2

I have two ZF2 projects. They share almost the same moduleset, I have built a CMS system. The page I call is the same at both project.

**The one eats 17MB of RAM (loading time: 917ms), the other 7MB (loading time: 216ms).**

Zend Developer Tools Toolbar - Memory Usage - says:

1. Session.validate (Session/SessionManager.php - Line:379) 5,75MB <-> 3,25MB
2. Option (Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php - Line: 128) 5,75MB <-> 1MB

These are the most significant differences, but I do not find the cause.

**Any idea would be appreciated! Thank you!**